# javascriptcore.framework iOS7 and libiOSjavascriptcore.a in same project

Tags: javascript, ios, javascriptcore

I am using libiOSjavascriptcore.a library in my application by which i can run JS in my apps.

Now from iOS 7javascriptcre.framework is available.

Now file names for both library and framework are same.

Issue is that I want to add support to my app from iOS5 to iOS7.

I want my app to use library in iOS5 apps and framework which apple provide default in iOS7. How can I achieve this.

Thanks in Advance